# Why can't I specify two fields in a return statement

Tags: java

I'm doing [exercise 1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/QandE/creating-questions.html) of the official Java tutorial. So far, I have this program:

```
public class Card {
    public final int rank;
    public final int suit;

    public Card(int rank, int suit){
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public final static int Diamonds = 1;
    public final static int Clubs =2;
    public final static int Hearts = 3;
    public final static int Spades =4;

    public final static int Ace =1;
    public final static int Deu=2;
    public final static int Three =3;
    public final static int Four =4;
    public final static int Five = 5;
    public final static int Six = 6;
    public final static int Seven = 7;
    public final static int Eight =8;
    public final static int Nine = 9;
    public final static int Ten =10;
    public final static int Jack =11;
    public final static int Queen =12;
    public final static int King=13;

    public int returnSuit() {
        return suit;
        return rank;
    }
}
```

However, Eclipse keeps giving me an "unreachable code" error for the second field in the `returnSuit` method. I've googled my problem but I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Method is `returnSuit` it should only return `suit`.

Comment: When the method is called it immediately returns `suit` and leaves the method. The line `return rank;` will never be executed and therefor is unreachable code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `return` in *Java* is the ending point of the current method. In that point, the method exists and returns the value specified.

It is giving you an error because you will never get to the second `return`, as the method already finished.

Answer (score 1):

you can't have multiple return statements one after another. when compiler see's return statement it basically terminates that method and return's to the previous control. if you  have two returns one after another, compiler is most definitely sure that thefirst return would return the value by terminating the method. your second return statement is never reaced, thus compiler complains `unreachable code` i guess you need something like below:

```
public int returnSuit(){
    if(somecond is true)
        return suit;
    else
        return rank;
}
```

Comment: thanks, why can't you have multiple return statements after each other?